# iOS 7 sync with iTunes 10.7

Tags: sync, itunes, iphone, ios

I was wondering if I can sync my iPhone 4S (with a not already *WiFi*-installed iOS 7) with iTunes **10.7** without upgrading it to the 11.x version…

If not in a standard way, perhaps it could be in a sort of unconventional way… I don't know, maybe by replacing a framework/file from the 11.x version…

Any chance ? (if can help in order to provide an answer, I have OS X 10.6.8)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a "not already WiFi-installed iOS 7"? But regardless, I'm fairly certain you need iTunes 11.1 to sync with iOS 7.

Comment: I actually have iOS 6.x on my iPhone, but I can do the upgrade to iOS 7 through WiFi (download and install) and without connect the iPhone to the Mac (the wired iTunes sync process).